# Find all local and global extrema of the function .

Tags: analysis, optimization

Find all local and global extrema of the function

$f (x, y, z) = x^3 + 3x^2 + e^{y^2+1} + z^2 - 3xz$

For this $f_x(x,y,z)=3x^2+6x-3z=0$

$f_y(x,y,z)=2ye^{y^2+1}=0$

$f_z(x,y,z)=2z-3x=0$..

Is this right way how we going to processed

according to the hints of both @Jsevillamo and @ Hermes...

i got the points $(x,y,z)=(\frac{-1}{3},0,\frac{1}{2})$

and the $H_f=\left(\begin{matrix} -2 & 0 & -3  \\ 0 & 2 & 0  \\ -3 & 0 & 2 &\end{matrix}\right)$

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the generic way to proceed is:

> **(1)** Find points $X \in \mathbb{R}^3$ s.t. $\nabla f(X) = 0$
>
> **(2)** Determine $\nabla^2f(X)$, the **Hessian**, to conclude whether a given $X$ is a local minimum or maximum, in order to get rid of *saddle
>   point*.
>
> **(3)** Investigate whether or not those local minimum (or max) might constitue **global** minimum (or max).

Now there are no general methods for **step (3)**. Here, for instance, it's easy to see that from the definition of $f$ that $f \rightarrow ±\infty$ as $x \rightarrow ±\infty$ and $y=z=0$, so that $f$ has no global maximum or minimun.

Comment: @Hermes..i solved something as i knew can you please help me to next

Answer (score 0):

From the system of equations you have found we can compute the critical points of the function (where the differential is $(0,0,0)$).

Since $2ye^{y²+1}=0$ it must be the case that either $y=0$ or $e^{y²+1}=0$. Since the latter is impossible, we have that $y=0$.

We also have from $f_z$ that $z = \frac{3x}{2}$, and thus substituting in $f_x$ we have an equation from which we can infere the possible values of $x$.

With those solutions in hand, we have to compute the Hessian $H_f$ (the matrix of second derivatives of $f$). Then if we substitute the solutions in $H_f$ and we find that $H_f$ is positive definite we have a local minima there, and if $H_f$ is negative definite then we are in a local maxima.

If $H_f$ is semidefinite or indefinite then we will have to observe how the function behaves in the neighborhood of the solution to reach a conclusion.

Also we will need to observe the limits as we go towards infinity to determine whether the local extrema are global or not.

Feel free to ping back if something is not clear.

Comment: @Jsevillamol...accourding to your hint i  got x=-1/3 , y=0, z=-1/2, can suggest me for  next..

Comment: i foud matrix to but i cant processed next can you help me

Comment: @Psuresh just plug the solution in the Hessian, and use [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) to see if it is definite positive/negative

Comment: @jseevillamol..i dont understan s.c

Comment: @Psuresh it merely says that a matrix is definite positive if the diagonal determinants are strictly positive, where by diagonal determinants I mean the square submatrices coming which result from eliminating repeteadly the last column and row of the Hessian, so for example the last diagonal determinant is the upper right cell of the matrix.